# Pixel manipulation with FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, pixel-manipulation

I'm using FabricJS  v1.5.0 and have a problem when manipulated pixel by pixel on the canvas.

```
this.canvas = new this.fabric.Canvas('canvas');
let imageData = this.canvas.contextContainer.getImageData(0, 0, this.canvas.getWidth(), this.canvas.getHeight());
//here a changed imageData

this.canvas.contextContainer.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
//data seted in canvas.

let imageAdd = new this.fabric.Image(image, {
          left: 100,
          top: 100,
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        });
this.canvas.add(imageAdd).setActiveObject(imageAdd);
//in this moment, the canvas don't have more the imageData setted
```

Why add image clear imageData? I need to transform imageData in FabricJS Object to add in canvas?

Comment: Where/how did you set the 'image' variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you do need to turn your image data into a fabricjs image. When you need to save the state of the canvas you can do this:

```
var dataUrl;
....
// Save canvas state
dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL()

// Make changes to the canvas
```

Then when you need to restore the canvas from it's saved state:

```
var img = fabric.Image.fromURL(dataUrl, function (i) {
    canvas.clear();
    canvas.add(i);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

You should then be able to add other images as before.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to find out is if your `image` is actually an image object, because `fabric.Image()` needs your image object.

If it's a URL or Blob format of your image ( which I guess it is ), you need to use `fabric.Image.fromURL()` and provide the `src` of the image not the whole image object.

Here is an example on how to create an instance of fabric.Image from a URL string

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(link, function(img) {
    img.set({
        id : 'someId',
        width : canvas.width / 2,
        height : canvas.height / 2
    });
    canvas.add(img).renderAll().setActiveObject(img);
});
```

Comment: can you Please provide snippet or fiddle for it ?

Comment: @mayurkukadiya you're welcome! consider upvoting my answer if it helped you, thanks!